# Gimp does not respond when I use Cage Transform tool

Tags: 15.10, gimp

When I use Cage Transform tool and I select the cage, the program works fine. But when I close the area, the program says "Transforming the region" (or something like that since I have Gimp in catalan), and then the program does not respond.

I have tried to:

- Reset the computer (of course).
- Change the drivers.
- Reinstall Gimp.
- Delete all Gimp plug-ins.

But nothing works.

Comment: This is happening to me as well, can anybody help?

Comment: [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1614593) caused by Ubuntu packagers chosing the wrong dependencies. There's a patch attached to the bug report for those who want to compile from the sources themselves, which only few want to do I guess. Not sure why the packagers didn't feel to fix it yet: it's still present in 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Adding PPA don't help for 16.04., cage still don't work with Gimp 2.8.22.
But snap solve this issue with gimp 2.10 here: https://snapcraft.io/gimp

Comment: Flatpack works better than snap for me https://www.gimp.org/downloads/